# How to filter out a portion of the text data with re.match or any other regex method with Python?

Tags: python, nlp, regex

I have the following data :

```
Node : WATER-7609-WR1 

IP Address : 172.20.150.81

Severity : 5 - Critical

ServerSerial : 50505223

SNSupportGroup : UC-WAN

Node Location : CO 160 WATER 8 FL RCV

Event Details : Unknown Not Link Down or Up trap on Serial Channel:  Unknown Severity: 4
NOTE:Configuration Item is not found in CMDB. Please update Incident with related Configuration Item
```

I am interested in all text after "Event Details :",
 I have used the the following function :

```
def eventdetails(text): 
   match =re.search(r'Event Details :[^.]*',text) 
   return match

print(eventdetails(dfnetcool_inc["Description"][3])) 

output: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(159, 292), match='Event Details : Unknown Not Link Down or Up trap >
```

--> Am not getting all of the text after Event Details. Perhaps there is an EOL charecter - how do I get remainder of the text, request your help, TIA!

Comment: Could you help us by indicating which part of the message you are interested in?

Comment: I am interested in all text after "Event Details :", I have used the the following function :                                                                                                            def eventdetails(text):
    match =re.search(r'Event Details :[^.]*',text)
    return match
print(eventdetails(dfnetcool_inc["Description"][3]))                                                          output: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(159, 292), match='Event Details : Unknown Not Link Down or Up trap >           --> Am not getting all of the text.

Comment: solved : I used -  match =re.findall(r'Event Details :[^*]+',flags= re.M, string= text)

Answer (score 2):

nice that you solved it. This would also work:

```
import re

def eventdetails(text): 
   match =re.search(r'Event Details :(.*)',text, flags=re.S) 
   return match

result = eventdetails(text)
print(result.group(0))
```